# Can my iOS6-compiled static library check an iOS app's compiled version?

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

I have an iOS static library that I'm compiling with iOS 6.1. What I'd like to do is run a check at compile time to see if an iOS application that is linking to my static library is compiled with iOS7 (and run some code in that event). Is there a way to do this? I've tried:

- The **__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED** macro but it returns the compiled OS version for my library (60100), not the application linking to it.
- Checking **NSFoundationVersionNumber** but that returns the system version of the device, not the app.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Per request, here's more info into what I'm trying to accomplish.

My iOS6-compiled static library serves full-screen ads. With iOS7's changes to how the status bar is displayed, my ads (UIViews w/UIWebViews) are appearing underneath the status bar elements. So, I'm trying to detect if the app that is using my static library is compiled with iOS7, so I can do things like adjust the origin of the aforementioned UIWebView down, adding a 20-point gray UIView object to the top of my main UIView object so the status bar elements are visible, etc. Also, it's just as important to check if the app's compiled against iOS6 so I don't apply the UI fixes incorrectly. Checking for the systemVersion property of UIDevice won't work as it'll return the same thing regardless of whether the app that's using my library is compiled on iOS6 or iOS7.

Comment: So you are asking how Apple accomplishes: "As a backward-compatibility mechanism, Apple frameworks sometimes check for the version of the SDK an application is built against, and, if it is an older SDK, modify the behavior for compatibility. This is done in cases where Apple predicts or discovers compatibility problems." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Overview/overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002001-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your predicament. You need to know if the compatibility mode is active or not. I would recommend upgrading your library to be built with iOS 7 anyway, as if the target app is built for iOS 7 your library views will look wrong even if you are built for iOS 6 as the runtime is dynamically linked and its characteristics are determined by the host app, not yours SDK.

Anyway, here's how I would accomplish making sure the your webview is displayed correctly:

Get the bounds for the window. The window always represents the size of the screen in a portrait orientation. The views are transformed into that space. The key here is the window on iOS 6 sizes its view controller to account for the status bar (except in apps with a hidden status bar), but on iOS 7 it is sized to go under the status bar. You can then find the status bar orientation, take the requisite 20px off the height (or width) of the window and use UIKit to transform the rect to co-ordinates in your local view

```
CGRect windowBounds = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bounds];
CGRect advertRect;
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isStatusBarHidden]) {
    advertRect = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] convertRect:advertRect
                                                                     toView:self.view];     
}
else{
    //status bar is not hidden
    CGRectEdge edge;
    switch ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            edge = CGRectMinXEdge;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            edge = CGRectMaxXEdge;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            edge = CGRectMaxYEdge;
            break;
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        default:
            edge = CGRectMinYEdge;
            break;
    }

    CGRect statusBarRect;
    CGRect remainingRect;

    CGRectDivide(windowBounds, &statusBarRect, &remainingRect, 20.0, edge);

    //converts from window co-ordinates to view co-ordinates
    advertRect = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] convertRect:advertRect
                                                                     toView:myView];
}
```

This rect will be the rect of all the remaining window space under the status bar area no matter which iOS you are running on. You should be able to use this to position your web view.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to search the app's Mach-O headers for LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS, which will tell you the SDK version that the app was linked against.

Answer (score 0):

You should use runtime introspection on the selectors you want to call.

E.g.

```
if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(barTintColor)]) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

Or if you must you can use the system version check

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion].floatValue < 7.000000) {
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:containerClass, nil] setTintColor:tintColor];
}
```

The introspection is better as it guarantees the method is available, and the above system check method is not reliable when comparing minor system versions.

Comment: the more zeros the more certain you are ;)

Comment: I'll write this in my next wallpaper... ; )

Comment: This was originally what I was thinking too. The problem is that I'm looking for the compiled OS version of the application linking to my static library, not necessarily the current device's OS.

Comment: Could you post more information into your question? Think less about the how and more about the why. If we know your end goal we can help more.

Comment: Done. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!